Linking with a custom-built pcc
I made a customized pcc build by doing doing the classical ./configure && make  -j$(nproc) && sudo make install on pcc cloned from https://github.com/IanHarvey/pcc.
It compiles a hello-world C file fine, but unlike the prebuilt pcc from the Ubuntu repo, it fails to link, giving the error message:
ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find -lpcc: No such file or directory
error: ld terminated with status 1

How do I fix this?

Edit:
Dear noncommenting, close-requesting downvoter: get over your pedantic need to have everything spelled out. These days, machines can infer that "compiling and linking a hello-world file" 99.9% means running:
$ pcc hw.c

(since this is about pcc) on some hw.c:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){ puts("hello world"); return 0; }

If machines can be this intelligent (or at least ask for more info politely), surely people can too.

See whether there is check or test target in the makefile and run that.  Otherwise, it appears that the install phase didn't put everything where it should.  Maybe rerun the make install, logging the output and ensuring that the “missing” files are installed.  Consider whether to configure to install in, say, /opt/pcc instead of /usr/local.

Thanks. Looks like they're not even generated for some reason. :/ I guess I'll take a look at what the ubuntu pcc build does differently.

The pcc repo only contains the core compiler.  You also need to download, compile and install the pcc-libs repo at https://github.com/IanHarvey/pcc-libs.  This includes the standard include files, libpcc, crtbegin and more.
It's likely the Ubuntu package combined the two repos into one package, or had one as a dependency on the other so it auto-installed.  THe EPEL 7 pcc package has them combined.
